# How to grep IPv4 NSString from HTML response?

Tags: ios, regex, ip-address, nsregularexpression

I need get WiFi LAN network's public IP address. I am trying to grep IP address string from http://wtfismyip.com/ 's response, but failed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://wtfismyip.com/ -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><link rel="canonical" href="./WTF is my IP ! !  _files/WTF is my IP ! !  .html">
...
...
...
</style><script>window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";</script><script>window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";</script></head><body><div id="main"><center><p></p>  
<h2>Your fucking IP address is:</h2>  
</center><center><p>220.233.211.182</p></center>  
<center><p></p><h2>Your host name is:</h2></center>  
<center><p>182.211.233.220.static.exetel.com.au</p>  
</center><center><p></p><h2>Geographic location of your IP address:</h2></center><center><p>Sydney, 02, Australia</p></center><center><p></p>  
...  
...  
nload/download-easy.html.en">Tor Browser Bundle!</a></li></ul><p class="halb"></p></div><p></p><p></p></body></html>
```

**I have write following Objective-C code to try to grep IP address out, but failed.**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wtfismyip.com/"]
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"ResponseString: %@",responseString);
NSString *regExpString = @"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regExpString
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:responseString
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [responseString length])];
NSLog(@"match is      : %@",[match description]);
NSLog(@"Public IP is  : %@",[responseString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
return [responseString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]] ;
```

The match is : (null)

Which part is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this regex

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

I was able to parse the ip from this page with this expression

Comment: It is still (NULL)  :(

Comment: did you escape the regex correctly? to use it as a NSString it has to look like this `@"\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b"`. I tried your code with that regex and it worked. Only in your last line you have to replace `[match rangeAtIndex:1]` with `[match rangeAtIndex:0]`

Comment: I did fix the escape the \. as XCode notice me. I have missed both \b escape....  Thanks a lot.